# -bash: pm2: command not found error on ec2

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2, npm-install, pm2

I have set npm's default directory by using the method outlined [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

I have attached a screenshot of the command I used below:
[image]

The `~/.profile` contains the following content:
[image]

It is working fine.

However, when I log out and log back in, and check the pm2 version, I run into the error below:

[image]

What is causing this issue?

The output for the following command are as follows:

`npm prefix -g` is `/home/ec2-user/.npm-global`

`npm prefix` is `/home/ec2-user`

`echo $PATH` is `/home/ec2-user/.npm-global/bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`

This issue is driving me nuts. I am unable to find any resources online which help with this issue. Solutions will be heavily appreciated.

Also, I have noticed an increase in disliking StackOverflow posts. If you decide to dislike this post, consider writing a comment on why, so this question can be improved to help future readers. Else, it will be assumed, that you didn't read the question and are spamming/trolling around.

Comment: The error `npm globalprefix incompatible with nvm` seems suspicious. I don't know how to offer a solution without reproducing your setup; however, you might take a look at some of these solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718528/nvm-is-not-compatible-with-the-npm-config-prefix-option

Answer (score 1):

What a coincidence to see you again. I take it my answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77258420/unable-to-start-pm2-in-linux-ec2-bash-pm2-command-not-found) didn't work... :( 
It would be better to comment or edit the last question, but oh well.

I would still guess that the problem is caused by multiple partial attempts to install nodejs, which are now fighting each other.

The error message in your screenshot (Your user's .npmrc file...) is especially enlightening.

Let's start from the beginning and try to undo the mess. Easiest would be to create a new EC2 machine, but to clean up an existing machine I would try this:

1. Check what files are in /root: `ls -la /root/`
2. Delete anything that sounds related node or npm or nvm. E.g. `.node`, `.npm`, `.npm-global`, `.npmrc`, `.nvm`
3. If `.profile` didn't exist before you started, delete it -- it clearly didn't help ([explanation of bash file priority](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash#:%7E:text=When%20bash%20is%20invoked,to%20inhibit%20this%20behavior.))
4. Check what files are in /etc/skel (this is the template containing unmodified default config files for new users): `ls -la /etc/skel/`
5. Look inside any filenames which are both in /etc/skel/ and in /root/ and compare the file contents with each other. If the file in /root/ contains any lines that sound related to node or npm or nvm, delete those lines.
6. Re-login.
7. Try running `node`, `npm`, `nvm`, `pm2` - all of them should say file not found
8. Run `grep -r npm-global /root /etc` to search for any remaining mentions of npm-global (there should be none)
9. OK, hopefully now nodejs is completely uninstalled

Now install node.js again. There are several ways to do it ("nvm" is one of them). I am not specifically familiar with EC2, but I found that Amazon has this official tutorial, which recommends nvm:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Re-login again.

With this, you should not see any error about things "incompatible with nvm" on login, and you DON'T need to follow https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally .

Then you can e.g. `npm install -g pm2` normally, and with some luck, it should just work.